# How to test whether a string contains the representation of an integer and nothing else?

Tags: php, type-conversion

Is there a function in PHP that converts string to int, however taking "int" seriously.

Casting to int or `intval` both try to be smart and perform additional math operations like rounding.

I have a solution -- using int cast, and then converting int back to string.

**If the result is the same**, then OK, but if not, it means string was representing **something else** (for example float).

```
"2.2" --> 2 --> "2" --> fail
"3" --> 3 --> "3" --> OK
```

But I wonder if there is something ready to use in PHP?

Comment: You mean: `$number == (string)(int)$number` ?

Comment: @Rizier123, yes (with `===`), as a check, if there was an int in the `$number` in the first place.

Comment: Btw: php doesn't try to be smart by applying any rounding to 2.2; it just stops at the dot because it's not a digit and hence not part of an integer.

Comment: @greenoldman your question is confusing, not explaining exactly what you need. I never seen so many answers deleting in a thread and so quickly.

Comment: The title of the question is slightly misleading. Both intval() and (int) 'take "int" seriously' when you're _converting_ the string. It seems that you want to test whether the string cotains only a valid integer representation and nothing else.

Comment: @VolkerK, yes exactly. This is what I mean by "int and only int".

Comment: "I never seen so many answers deleting in a thread and so quickly" - I think there are two reasons a) not reading the question completely b) difficulty to come up with a "better" soluton than already stated in the question.

Comment: @VolkerK  most probably yes. But that was fun watching (rarely seen on SO)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
function StrictIntVal($x)
{
  // If we already have an integer
  if(is_int($x)) return $x;

  // Check we have a string
  if(!is_string($x)) return false;

  // Check the string only contains digits (and optional sign)
  if(!preg_match("/^[\+\-]?\d+$/", $x)) return false;

  return intval($x);
}
```

Comment: I have added the handling of an optional sign at the beginning of the string. If you want to have a functionality, that is not already there, you have to program it. Your current approach will fail for "+2" or "02" for example.

Comment: Ah, yes, good catch :-). Since I need only string conversion, I will use only your regex. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @VolkerK Thanks for the nudge :)

Comment: And no need to escape `+`,  and `-` in this case neither ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK, true for plus, minus means range :-)

Comment: That's why I wrote "in this case". In this case pcre is smart enough to detect that `-` does in fact _not_ mean range ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are looking for the function `is_numeric()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Will tell you wether the string represents a number or not.

Comment: I am not :-), quote "'9.1' is numeric". I am talking about integers.